# Help identifying a component from a barcode scanner

Tags: identification, components, repair

I have a broken Honeywell model 1902 barcode scanner that I want to repair. It is the component labelled "6409" as shown in the photo:

[image]
.

Comment: That's just "6409"; the small circle is the pin 1 mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be this IC:

Transistor: P-MOSFET; unipolar; -20V; -4A; 1.3W; TSOP6  Manufacturer part number: AO6409A  TME Symbol: AO6409A

Reference: https://www.tme.com/in/en/details/ao6409a/smd-p-channel-transistors/alpha-omega-semiconductor/

I can see that Pin 2 is not connected and in the IC schematic, Pin 1 and Pin 2 is connecting to "D"

Answer (score -3):

It's a 2 phase half wave motor pre driver for fan motors. Dataheetcatalog. Com leave off the o its BA6409F

Comment: Donavon pire - Hi, Thanks for trying to help. However the IC in the photo has a 6-pin (e.g. SOT-23-6) package, but the [datasheet](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/922/BA6409F-pdf.php) for the BA6409F (which seems to be an old ROHM IC) shows that it has an SOP8 package. Therefore that identification cannot be correct :(